# Counter-example about càdlàg functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm looking for 2 real functions $f,g$ defined on an interval $[a,b]$ such that:

1. $f/g$ is positive non-decreasing on $[a,b]$
2. $fg$ is càdlàg
3. $f/g$ is not càdlàg

This is to find a counter-example to the the statement: if $fg$ is càdlàg and $f/g$ is positive non-decreasing, then $f/g$ is càdlàg. Maybe I am wrong and this statement is correct, but since we can find $f$ càdlàg and $g$ not càdlàg such that $fg$ is càdlàg, I am guessing adding that $f/g$ is positive non-decreasing is not much. Unfortunately, I cannot find a pair that satisfies that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the non cadlag function $\phi(x)=1_{(\frac{a+b}{2},b]}(x)$ let
$$
f(x)=e^{\phi(x)}\,,\quad g(x)=e^{-\phi(x)}\,.
$$
Then $fg\equiv 1$ and
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=e^{2\phi(x)}
$$
is non decreasing and not cadlag.